# How to deselecting (Remove Focus ) a specific property in MFCPropertyGridCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I am working in an MFC application with `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`. We have `SetCurSel()` function for selecting a required property. Is there any way to deselecting that property(exact opposite of `SetCurSel()`)?

The problem is

1. Having lot of groups in property grid control
2. I am focusing on the on group name
3. while hitting the TAB key the focus is shifting  to another control (out side of Property grid control) but the the selection at the group name is not changed.

So I want to remove the selection at the group name if I hit the TAB key to go to another control.

Comment: Try `SetCurSel(NULL)`

Comment: Is your idea to make a line read-only? If it is, `pProp->AllowEdit(FALSE)` seems a better approach to me.

Comment: Nope.  Need to remove focus/ highlighting  on the property name field